# Deploying a Printer (hosted on a print server) using Group Policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

Good day!

May I know the difference between the two? (please see image below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE6eS.png

I have been trying this for a while now and seems to be not working and I think I missed a lot here. Just wanted to know the following.

1. Where should I implement the printer? is it on the User or Computer side?
2. I have yet to put any driver yet which I think I should set one and I'm not sure where this will be inputted?
3. on the printer itself, should I put in the full network address with the name (e.g., office Printer) or like the printer name (e.g., e-1234657HPLink)?

If I my questions doesn't the ideal installation feel free to point me on the right direction. :)

Thanks heaps.

On how to deploy printer with GPO.

Answer (score 0):

Both options will install a printer, albeit in a slightly different way.

1. I'd recommend installing the printers on a per-user basis (User Configuration) versus Computer Configuration, as it will give the individual more control. You probably want to use the **Windows Settings -> Deployed Printers** option if it's something you want to enforce versus merely being a "suggestion" that the user can modify/remove when using **Control Panel Settings -> Printers**
2. The drivers are provided by the printer server. If the print server uses the same architecture as the client, it will provide the same drives upon installation. You can adjust the drivers on the print server by going to **Printer Properties -> Sharing (tab) -> Additional Drivers**
3. The printer should be specified under **Deployed Printers** using the full network path where the printer is shared (e.g. **\\printserver\printername**)

To deploy using GPO, you need to create the Group Policy using **Group Policy Management** on a domain controller, then assign it to the computer/user to which it applies, usually based on the appropriate OU within Active Directory.